# French MacBook Pro keyboard on Ubuntu Karmic

Tags: linux, ubuntu, keyboard, ubuntu-9.10, macbook

I am trying to configure my Keyboard on Ubuntu Karmic, but the problem is that the gnome-control panel override my xorg.conf configuration. And it is a problem since gnome-control-panel doesn't configure my lv3 key correctly.

Do you have any idea of how I can see the configuration file and try to fix this ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should help answer the question :

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro

and for me this :
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBookPro3-1/Karmic