# MacBook Pro 2017 Linux Keyboard Layout

Tags: linux, keyboard-layout, macbook-pro

I'm looking for the right keyboard configuration for Linux.
I've tried [this](https://superuser.com/questions/65386/french-macbook-pro-keyboard-on-ubuntu-karmic) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235533/how-to-set-keyboard-layout-for-a-macbook-pro) posts but all I get is a *close* match.

Some keys are not matching. For exemple, by typing `£` I obtain `]`, `@` gives `²` and some other keys are misplaced, the most important ones being `~` and `|`.

This is my 2017 `MacBookPro14,1`'s keyboard, any idea which configuration this might be and how it would be enabled on Linux?

[image: IMG_1989.png]